# Migrate primary key in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've just recently added a primary key to my Realm model and therefor i keep getting below error. i've tried to migrate in appdelegate but still get the rror. all i've done is adding the `propertyKey()` function. How can i migrate properly?

```
Migration is required for object type 'Organization' due to the following errors:
- Property 'id' has been made a primary key."
```

However i've allready added below to appdelegate:

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                // The enumerate(_:_:) method iterates
                // over every Person object stored in the Realm file
                migration.enumerate(Organization.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    // combine name fields into a single field

                }
            }
    })
```

here is my object

```
class Location: Object {
    var id: Int = 0
    var longitude: Double = 0
    var latitude: Double = 0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

}

class Organization: Object {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var image: NSData = NSData()
    let locations = List<Location>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the Model didn't have a primary key before, you can fix it by doing so:

```
    //MARK: Realm Migrations
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        // bump the schema version to 2
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            migration.enumerate(Organization.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                // make sure to check the version accordingly
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                    // the magic happens here: `id` is the property you specified 
                    // as your primary key on your Model
                    newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = "id"
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

I hope it helps,
Cheers!

Comment: so would it be newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = 0 (or any other int)

Answer (score 2):

1. open AppDelegate.swift
2. add following code to the func application:

   ```
   let config = Realm.Configuration(

   // set a new version number, the version number must bigger than before

       // if you never set it, it's 0

       schemaVersion: 1,

       migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

       if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
         // do nothing
         }
       })

       // tell Realm the new config should be used 

       Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

       // open realm file and it will do auto-migration

       let realm = Realm()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Update: On Realm 2.8.3, the property `primaryKeyProperty` is not necessary anymore for the migration.

I can't edit the ReCamilio answer, sorry.

Comment: and the entire `migrationBlock` can be ignored if there is no need to migrate any other data. `primaryKeyProperty` takes care of itself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38844738/281474