# Realm swift change primaryKey

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

So I have Realm object

```
class RegistrationPlateDB: RLMObject {

    dynamic var registrationPlate : String = ""
    dynamic var user : String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "registrationPlate"
    } ...
```

and would like to change it to

```
class RegistrationPlateDB: Object {

    dynamic var plateID : Int = -1
    dynamic var registrationPlate : String = ""
    dynamic var name : String = ""
    dynamic var user : String = ""


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "plateID"
    } ....
```

So i've written a migration

```
 migration.enumerate(RegistrationPlateDB.className()) { oldObject, newObject in

        newObject!["name"] = ""
        newObject!["user"] = ""
        newObject!["registrationPlate"] = ""
        newObject!["plateID"] = -1
        newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = "plateID";  
 }
```

but I get an error probably because of the primaryKey change, since if I leave that line out it works but the primary key doesn't change.

Can someone give me any idea how to change the primaryKey.

EDIT: The first object was written for Objective-c realm

EDIT2: Or if anybody would know how could I make plateID autoincrement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Katsumi from Realm here. You don't need to attempt change primary key in the migration block.

We always automatically update the schema to the latest version, and the only thing that you have to handle in the migration block is adjusting your data to fit it (e.g. if you rename a property you have to copy the data from the old property to the new one in the migration block).

So `newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = "plateID";` is not needed.

I think your migration block should be like the following:

```
migration.enumerate(RegistrationPlateDB.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    newObject!["user"] = oldObject!["user"]
    newObject!["registrationPlate"] = oldObject!["registrationPlate"]
    newObject!["plateID"] = Int(oldObject!["registrationPlate"] as! String)
}
```

If you'd like to assign sequence numbers to `plateID`, for example:

```
var plateID = 0
migration.enumerate(RegistrationPlateDB.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    newObject!["user"] = oldObject!["user"]
    newObject!["plateID"] = plateID
    plateID += 1
}
```

Comment: I understood the idea of not need for declaring new primarykey in migration, so I tried your suggestion, but I think the problem now is that oldObject!["registrationPlate"] is a word, so I don't think that could get trough.

So if you could tell me if there is any way to set plateID as autoincrement in migration?

Comment: EDIT: Or if there is a way to rename an object so I could create new one the same as old one, then recreate old one an copy data.

Comment: @schmru I updated the answer. Realm doesn't support auto-increment feature. So you should implement that feature yourself. If you do not need a serial number, using `NSUUID` is the easiest way. If you'd like to sort with the primary key, you can use `NSDate()` instead.

Comment: I saw it, thanks big time, that was what I was looking for.
Thanks again @kishikawa katsumi

Comment: This "newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = "plateID"" is all over the pace as the solution for primaryKey changes or additions...     But this should be the right answer for all those cases